# WPF double animation with delay

Tags: wpf, animation, opacity

I am trying to change the opacity of a rectangle from 0 to 1 and back from 1 to 0, but also to wait 2 seconds at every step. so i want 2 seconds to be 1, after that to change it to 0 in 500 milliseconds and then wait another 2 seconds with the opacity 0 and going again in 500 milliseconds to 1 and so one.

I have this code:

```
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(forwardDoubleAnimation,
            new PropertyPath("(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(reverseDoubleAnimation,
           new PropertyPath("(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"));

        forwardDoubleAnimation.Completed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            reverseStoryboard.Begin();
        };

        reverseDoubleAnimation.Completed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            forwardStoryboard.Begin();
        };
```

But i have an exception on reverseStoryboard.Begin() that says i didn't set a target property for it.

Is there a way to do it using a single animation and to set a property in order to wait?

Comment: I see there are 2 properties: AccelerationRatio and DecelerationRatio but i can't figure out how they work. I set them to 0.5 and it works almost as i want to, but it seems like the time from 0 opacity is not the same as the time for 1 opacity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take advantage from the fact that, although an Opacity has values in the range 0 to 1, you may set values lower than 0 or greater than 1.

If you animate an Opacity from -2 to 3 in 2.5 second, in the first second it goes from -2 to 0, which is 0 effectively, then it goes from 0 to 1 in 0.5 seconds, then from 1 to 3, i.e. effectively 1 in another second.

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = -2,
    To = 3,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};

rectangle.Fill.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, animation);
```

Comment: I didn't think of this solution. But even if it's a hack, it works. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a hack. It's straightforward.

Comment: This works exactly as described, however, I'm not clear how WPF knows to take 1 second, 0.5 seconds, and then 1 second again. How does it work and how can it be controlled (if possible)?

Comment: @JRGuay The animation goes continuously from -2 to 3 in 2.5 seconds. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you (please change durations according to your issue).

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Rectangle" Fill="Red" Width="500" Height="400">
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:3" BeginTime="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
```

Comment: Nop, that doesn't work. BeginTime is for the entire animation, for for every cycle. So all it does is to delay the animation after the trigger was triggered. After that everything works as before.